# Cómo utilizar función en método de un objeto

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo un objeto agenda.js con un método `visualizar()`

```js
 visualizar() {
            this.muro.innerHTML = "";
            for (let elemento of this.apuntes) {
               crearNota(elemento);
            }
```

Donde quiero utilizar la función `crearNota` que esta en el archivo del html

```js
function crearNota(elemento){
                let nota = document.createElement("li");
                let fechaNueva = document.createElement("input");
                fechaNueva.type = "date";
                let anotacionNueva = document.createElement("input");
                fechaNueva.value = elemento.fecha;
                anotacionNueva.value = elemento.anotacion;
                nota.appendChild(fechaNueva);
                nota.appendChild(anotacionNueva);
                crearHecho(nota, elemento);
                crearBoton(nota, "edit");
                crearBoton(nota, "remove");
                this.muro.appendChild(nota);
                fechaNueva.disabled = true;
                anotacionNueva.disabled = true;
            }
```

Al ejecutar el html cuando llamo al método `visualizar()` no me reconoce la función `crearNota` como definida.
He intentado importar el html en el javascript pero tampoco he sido capaz.
¿Como lo hago?

Comment: Si bien has incluido algo de código, es recomendable incluir un [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El único problema es el orden en el que se cargan los dos archivos. Para puedas ejecutar la función crearNota desde dentro del archivo agenda.js, la función crearNota tiene que estar ya cargada. Esto es muy fácil de solucionar, solo tienes que declarar tu función antes de incluir el script agenda.js de forma que cuando tu llames a la función visualizar, el navegador ya haya "parseado" la función crearNota.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>


    <script>

        function crearNota(elemento){
            let nota = document.createElement("li");
            let fechaNueva = document.createElement("input");
            fechaNueva.type = "date";
            let anotacionNueva = document.createElement("input");
            fechaNueva.value = elemento.fecha;
            anotacionNueva.value = elemento.anotacion;
            nota.appendChild(fechaNueva);
            nota.appendChild(anotacionNueva);
            crearHecho(nota, elemento);
            crearBoton(nota, "edit");
            crearBoton(nota, "remove");
            this.muro.appendChild(nota);
            fechaNueva.disabled = true;
            anotacionNueva.disabled = true;
        }


    </script>


    <script src="agenda.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```